# mongodb: can change "multiple limit 1 aggregation" to one aggregation?

Tags: mongodb, geospatial

[image]

## What I want to do

I’m implementing food delivery application.

when a location of user is given (GeoJsonPoint), I want to know what categories are available on that point.

each shops have `delivery_areas` which is list of GeoJsonPolygon

for example… (see the picture)

- there are four rectangles represent delivery area of each shop (chicken, chicken2, burger, pizza)
- point of user has given
- point intersects with chicken, chicken2, burger
- I want distinct result. so the result should be ["chicken", "burger"]

I want to find the most efficient way to query this.
(usually, there are more than 50 shops per each category)

## what I did

I have a shop collection

```py
@dataclasses.dataclass
class ShopDoc(BaseDoc):
    name: str
    category_codes: list[str]  # "chicken", "pizza", ...
    delivery_areas: list[ShopDeliveryAreaDoc]  # this is GeoJsonPolygon
```

and I’m doing following query with geo sphere index

```py
# index
await self._collection.create_index(
            [("category_codes", pymongo.ASCENDING), ("delivery_areas.poly", pymongo.GEOSPHERE)]
        )

# count query with limit 1
async def exists_by_category_and_point_intersects(self, category_code: CategoryCode, point: GeoJsonPoint) -> bool:
        cnt = await self._collection.count_documents(
            {
                "category_codes": category_code,
                "delivery_areas": {"$elemMatch": {"poly": {"$geoIntersects": {"$geometry": asdict(point)}}}},
            },
            limit=1,
        )
        return bool(cnt)
```

I’m doing following aggregation (I extracted from Motor)

```py
[
        {'$match': {'category_codes': <CategoryCode.JAPANESE: 'japanese'>, 'delivery_areas': {'$elemMatch': {'poly': {'$geoIntersects': {'$geometry': {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [127.005926, 37.49006]}}}}}}},
        {'$limit': 1},
        {'$group': {'_id': 1, 'n': {'$sum': 1}}},
]
```

- for each category, I do above query, parallely. (so if there are total 7 categories, I do 7 aggregation queries in parallel with asyncio.gather())

## My question

I think there are network overhead. can I do this in one query?

(I don't want to use `distinct()`. if shops getting many, and many, there are more duplicate category shops I don't need. after performance test, above query was faster than `distinct()` approach.

or any other approaches to make this query more efficient would be appreciated

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Get rid of the `category_codes` filter in the `$match` (or use `$in` with all 7 categories) and then change the `_id` in the `$group` to be on `$category_codes` (may have to `$unwind` first

Comment: `Get rid of the category_codes filter in the $match (or use $in with all 7 categories)` -> what about limit 1...? if we get rid of category_codes filter, we can't use limit 1

Comment: Yes, the `$limit` would have to be removed as well